# Replace usage of new Gson().fromJson() with com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper covering all the cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, gson, json-deserialization

Currently we are using Gson to convert a JSON String to Map<String, String>. **It is required to eliminate use of Gson completely and replace it with ObjectMapper.**

Currently if we are to convert following Json String to a Map<String, String>

`"{"jwt":abc.def.ghi}"`

Note that the value against the key "jwt" is not a string.

```
String jsonString = "{\"jwt\":abc.def.ghi}";
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>(){}.getType();
Map<String, String> tokens = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Gson successfully converts it to

`tokens = {"jwt":"abc.def.ghi"}`

Corresponding Code using ObjectMapper:

```
Map<String, String> tokens = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {});
```

When tried using ObjectMapper, following exception is thrown:

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException Unrecognised token 'abc.def.ghi' found ....

The issue is that unlike Gson, ObjectMapper is not able to parse `abc.def.ghi` to `"abc.def.ghi"`.

What should be my correct approach to achieve the required result.

I have tried `objectMapper.writeValueAsString()` before passing it to the `readValue()`. Still no progress.

Comment: That is not a valid JSON string. The value `abc.def.ghi` needs to be enclosed in quotes. Looks like Google's Gson library is more forgiving. Jackson is much more strict.

Comment: At first glance Jackson only seems to support missing quotes for property _names_, not property _values_ (although according to the spec both is malformed).

Comment: See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/issues/723

Comment: Thanks @Marvin, this does give some clarity about how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple; naïve solution would be to use a regular expression to fix the offending JSON:

Pattern: `(?<=":\s?)(?<unquoted>[^\{\}"]+)(?=,?)`

This pattern includes a positive lookbehind that checks for a preceding quote. followed by a colon and an optional space. This would be a potential key/prop.

```java
import java.util.Map;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Deserializer {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private static final TypeReference<Map<String, String>> mapType;

    static {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapType = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() { };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        String invalidJsonString = "{\"jwt\":abc.def.ghi}";
        String jsonString = fixUnquotedJsonValues(invalidJsonString);
        Map<String, String> tokens = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, mapType);

        System.out.println(tokens);
    }

    public static String fixUnquotedJsonValues(String invalidJson) {
        return invalidJson.replaceAll(
                "(?<=\\\":\\s?)(?<unquoted>[^\\{\\}\\\"]+)(?=,?)",
                "\"${unquoted}\"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, 

As mentioned by @Marvin, Jackson does not provide built in deserialiser for the cases I mentioned, I will have to look into the variety of cases that might arises due to unavailability of a flexible deserialiser.

Comment: @FaizanAhmed well, the issue is your data, not the parser. The data must be valid JSON to be parsed by a JSON deserializer; plain-and-simple. There is really no way around this, unless you create your own fixer script like I have presented above.

Comment: Correct, the data is not with a proper syntax which is the real issue.